# ruby on rails url_for breaks when placing more than one variable into a route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

For a rails 3 project, I am trying to create seo urls like

```
/recipes/123/lasagna
```

My recipe model has a name property, and in the routes.rb I have specified the following:

```
resources :recipes, :path => "recipes", :except => [:show]
get :path => "recipes/:id/:name", :controller => :recipes, :action => :show, :as => :recipe
```

the controllers work as desired, but

```
url_for
```

and

```
recipe_path
```

break
- it doesn't seem to know what to use for :name

I would like it to work the default way - using

```
recipe_path(recipe)
```

a workaround would be to use

```
recipe_path(:id => recipe.id, :name => recipe.name)
```

that is not really pretty - and it would mean I have to modify all of my views

1. Is adding :name the correct approach to add the name to an url?
2. How can I get recipe_path to work properly?

Comment: Try switching the order of your two lines in your routes file.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have added *recipes/:id/:name* to your routes file you can leave out the *:id=> and :name=>*. You can just do this: recipe_path(recipe.id, recipe.name)